gtksourceview: syntax highlight for language groff in gedit
Sciancisco and I developed a syntax highlighter for the Groff markup language to be used with Gedit, Pluma, Xed etc. I installed it in /usr/share/gtksourceview-4/language-specs/groff.lang and it always worked fine, but now I'm using Debian Trixie and it doesn't work anymore. Any clue?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
COPYRIGHT:
==========
Gedit groff syntax highlight. A definition of the groff syntax for
GtkSourceView.

Copyright (C) 2022 - Daniel Dias Rodrigues. All rights reserved.
Copyright (C) 2020 - Sciancisco. All rights reserved.

This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any
later version.

This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY
WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License along
with this library; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc.,
51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA.

AVAILABILITY:
=============
Originally available at:
    * https://gist.github.com/nerun/6f57b9a0dd6681d3ea9a5886e418e9b9

Sciancisco's version originally available at:
    * https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/1984415
    * https://gist.github.com/Sciancisco/d1f5f1ea50481633ee1a2d270416543b

CHANGES against Sciancisco's version:
=====================================
    * <language>
        * name: the "G" of "Groff" was capitalized.
    * <metadata>
        * mimetypes and globs: completely changed based upon "All known MIME
          types" and their filename patterns, available at
          https://www.digipres.org/formats/mime-types/
    * <definitions><context>
        * comment-new and comment-old: the "." (dot) was included as part of the
          comment. Added "\.".
-->
<language id="groff" name="Groff" version="2.0" _section="Markup">

    <metadata>
        <property name="mimetypes">application/x-troff;application/x-troff-man;text/troff</property>
        <property name="globs">*.1;*.2;*.3;*.4;*.5;*.6;*.7;*.8;*.groff;*.man;*.roff</property>
    </metadata>

    <styles>
        <style id="comment" name="Comment" map-to="def:comment"/>
        <style id="escaped-character" name="Escaped Character" map-to="def:special-char"/>
        <style id="macro" name="Macro" map-to="def:function"/>
        <style id="request" name="Request" map-to="def:builtin"/>
        <style id="preprocessor" name="Preprocessor Macro" map-to="def:preprocessor"/>
    </styles>

    <definitions>
        <context id="groff">
            <include>

            <context id="comment-new" style-ref="comment" class="comment">
                <start>\.\\#</start>
                <end>$</end>
            </context>

            <context id="comment-old" style-ref="comment" class="comment">
                <start>\.\\"</start>
                <end>$</end>
            </context>

            <!-- Here starts the escape sequences mimicking the groff spec.
            If one wants to implement the entire spec, have fun:
            https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~trent/gnu/groff/groff.html#SEC52
            -->
            <context id="escape-bracket" style-ref="escaped-character" class="no-spell-check">
                <start>\\[[]</start>
                <end>[]]</end>
            </context>

            <context id="escape-bracket-parameter" style-ref="escaped-character" class="no-spell-check">
                <start>\\.[[]</start>
                <end>[]]</end>
            </context>

            <context id="escape-parenthesis" style-ref="escaped-character" class="no-spell-check">
                <match>\\[(]..</match>
            </context>

            <context id="escape-parenthesis-parameter" style-ref="escaped-character" class="no-spell-check">
                <match>\\.[(]..</match>
            </context>

            <context id="escape-simple-parameter" style-ref="escaped-character" class="no-spell-check">
                <match>\\..</match>
            </context>

            <context id="escape-simple" style-ref="escaped-character" class="no-spell-check">
                <match>\\.</match>
            </context>

            <!-- Highlight preprocessors -->
            <!-- Maybe add preprocessor syntax coloring. -->
            <!-- Many preprocessors are missing. -->
            <context id="eqn" style-ref="preprocessor" class="no-spell-check">
            <!-- Could be nice to add in line highlight with "delim" eqn command -->
                <start>^\.EQ(\s|$)</start>
                <end>^\.EN</end>
            </context>

            <context id="pic" style-ref="preprocessor" class="no-spell-check">
                <start>^\.PS(\s|$)</start>
                <end>^\.PE</end>
            </context>

            <context id="tbl" style-ref="preprocessor" class="no-spell-check">
                <start>^\.TS(\s|$)</start>
                <end>^\.TE</end>
            </context>

            <context id="chem" style-ref="preprocessor" class="no-spell-check">
                <start>^\.cstart(\s|$)</start>
                <end>^\.cend</end>
            </context>

            <context id="refer-opt" style-ref="preprocessor" class="no-spell-check">
                <start>^\.R1(\s|$)</start>
                <end>^\.R2</end>
            </context>

            <context id="refer-cite" style-ref="preprocessor">
                <start>^\.[[]</start>
                <end>^\.[]]</end>
            </context>

            <!-- General macro and request matching -->
            <context id="macro" style-ref="macro" class="no-spell-check">
                <match>^\.[A-Z0-9_]+</match>
            </context>

            <context id="request" style-ref="request" class="no-spell-ckeck">
                <match>^\.[a-z]+</match>
            </context>

            </include>
        </context>
    </definitions>

</language>


I found the answer.
I am using Gedit 46.2 (Debian Trixie) and, since version 45, gedit is using libgedit-gtksourceview-300-0 as explained in Gedit's Gitlab Repo. So, the right place to put a custom syntax highlight for Gedit 45+ is:
/usr/share/libgedit-gtksourceview-300/language-specs
Also, just to you know, my groff syntax highlight was merged to GtkSourceView:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtksourceview/-/merge_requests/371

The intro page says that gedit and so on search for the *.lang files for GtkSourceView 5 in
~/.local/share/gtksourceview-5/language-specs/
/usr/share/gtksourceview-5/language-specs/

Your Debian release might be using version 5 rather than 4,
so you might try moving your file to
~/.local/share/gtksourceview-5/language-specs/groff.lang
or
/usr/share/gtksourceview-5/language-specs/groff.lang

Thank you for trying to help. I found the answer. I am using Gedit 46.2, and since Gedit 45, gedit is using libgedit-gtksourceview-300-0, the right place to put a custom syntax is: /usr/share/libgedit-gtksourceview-300/language-specs.

Uh, and my syntax was merged to gtksourceview: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtksourceview/-/merge_requests/371
